# how to filter first occurrence of an element with different attributes from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to filter first occurrence based on both element and it's attribute. here element is same but based on attribute we have to take the first occurrence.

my xml look like below:

```
    <block ID="IF5">
        <codes ID="IF5" md.mnem="hg2">
            <info>
                <name>ARTICLE</name> 
                <designator>1</designator>
            <info>
        </codes>
        <codes ID="IF5" md.mnem="hg2c">
            <info>
                <headtext>PUBLIC</headtext>
            </info>
        </codes>
        <codes ID="IF5" md.mnem="hg2">
            <info>
                <name>ARTICLE</name> 
                <designator>1</designator>
            </info>
        </codes>
        <codes ID="IF5" md.mnem="hg2c">
            <info>
                <headtext>PUBLIC</headtext>
            </info>
        </codes>
    </block>
```

output xml should look like:

```
        <block ID="IF5">
        <codes ID="IF5" md.mnem="hg2">
            <info>
                <name>ARTICLE</name> 
                <designator>1</designator>
            <info>
        </codes>
        <codes ID="IF5" md.mnem="hg2c">
            <info>
                <headtext>PUBLIC</headtext>
            </info>
        </codes>
    </block>
```

I am trying to use template match like below:

```
<xsl:template match="codes.head[@md.mnem='hg*c' and position() &gt; 1]" />
<xsl:template match="codes.head[@md.mnem='hg*' and position() &gt; 1]" />
```

can anyone please help me to solve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the positional predicate separately and last e.g. `[position() > 1]` e.g. `match="codes.head[@md.mnem='hg2c'][position() > 1]"`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Honnen, but it's not working. I tried like below..                          
    <xsl:template match="codes[@md.mnem='hg*'][position() > 1]" />
    <xsl:template match="codes[@md.mnem='hg*c'][position() > 1]" />                                       can you please provide some sample.

Comment: @SaiPrasadMukthapuram, there is no wild card asterisk `*` in string comparisons so I am not sure what you want to express with `codes[@md.mnem='hg*']`.

Comment: it's working with the exact text(hg2c). but I was trying to make it generic. like if i have multiple <block> 's with different patterns like (hg1c, hg2c, hg3c). but it's solve the issue, i just need to add a separate template match for each. Big thanks @Martin Honnen :)

Comment: Hi @Martin Honnen,  In the above example I am taking  md.mnem="hg2c", but it can be any number in the place of * (hg*c).  I have to filter one occurrence of each such number. i.e, if I have hg3c and hg5c multiple times  I have to consider only once. Is the any way to achieve this. I am trying with  `<xsl:key name="hgmatch" match="codes[@md.mnem='hg*']" use="@md.mnem"/>` and collect distinct values & loop is over. but I am new to XSLT facing some difficulty to do it.  Thanks in advance

Comment: @SaiPrasadMukthapuram, please don't try to explain new problems in a comment, ask a new question with the details like minimal but complete and representative sample of XML input, wanted output, current output and the code you have tried. Also explain which XSLT processor and/or XSLT version you use.